# sort keys in hash of array by the number of elements in the array

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I have a hash of arrays.

```
%HoA = (
    'C1' =>  ['1', '3', '3', '3'],
    'C2' => ['3','2'],
    'C3' => ['1','3','3','4','5','5'],
    'C4'  => ['3','3','4'],
    'C5' => ['1'],
);
```

The values in the array don't matter per se. I would like to sort the keys by the size of the array in descending order. The output should look like.

```
C3  # this key contains an array with the most elements
C1
C4
C2
C5  # this key contains an array with the least elements
```

I don't know why this isn't working.

```
foreach my $key ( sort { $HoA{$b} <=> $HoA{$a}} keys %HoA ) {
    print "$key\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must compare the array sizes:

```
foreach my $key ( sort { scalar @{$HoA{$b}} <=> scalar @{$HoA{$a}}} keys %HoA ) {
    print "$key\n";
}
```

Comment: `{ @{ $HoA{$b} } <=> @{ $HoA{$a} } }` also works (w/o `scalar`), since the numeric comparison forces a scalar context.