# How to sort hash of arrays by array size

Tags: perl

I have a hash of arrays and I would like to sort them by the array size.

Here is my code so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash_array = (
    "array_1" => ["apple", "ball", "cat"],
    "array_2" => ["def", "leppard", "rocks", "too"],
    "array_3" => ["italian", "pastry", "missing", "cherry", "top"],
);

# Length of array_1
my $array_1_size = @{$hash_array{"array_1"}};
print "Should print three: $array_1_size\n";

# Found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722286
# But my result remains unsorted
foreach my $key ( sort { $hash_array{$b} <=> $hash_array{$a}} keys %hash_array ) {
    print "key: $key\n";
}
```

I understand how to get an individual array's size, but I'm not sure how to combine that with a sort function.

I copied the last foreach block from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722286/sort-keys-in-hash-of-array-by-the-number-of-elements-in-the-array) but that solution does not work for me as my output is not ordered. I had some questions about the last block of code:

1. I do not see $b and $a referenced earlier. Is this a built in reference that the sort function understands?
2. The solution appears to have worked for the original poster, but it is not working in my case. Yet our original goals are similar. What am I missing in order to get an ordered output based on array size?
3. What is the best way to sort the hash of arrays by array size in ascending and descending order?

Comment: If you look at the question you referenced, the poster says *"I don't know why this isn't working"* about the code you copied. The answer he accepted is what you should be copying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close. As written, you were comparing the array references, which are more or less memory addresses. I modified your code slightly to give you what you're looking for:

```
foreach my $key ( sort { scalar(@{$hash_array{$b}}) <=> scalar(@{$hash_array{$a}}) } keys %hash_array ) {
    print "key: $key\n";
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I knew it was something small. Thanks :)

Comment: There is no need for the calls to `scalar` as the `<=>` operator applies scalar context. `@{$hash_array{$b}} <=> @{$hash_array{$a}}` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The sort function is exactly that - an anonymous sub. You're not limited to a single comparison, you just need to finish with something that returns -1, 0 or 1. And yes, `$a` and `$b` are the two values being compared - they can be scalars or references.

You might solve your problem like this:

```
foreach my $key (sort { 
                        my $length_a = scalar @{$hash_array{$a}};
                        my $length_b = scalar @{$hash_array{$b}};
                        $length_b <=> $length_a
                      } keys %hash_array) {
    ...
}
```

I know that could be reduced to a one-liner, but the point is to show how you can have more than a single comparison inside a `sort` sub.

Comment: Deliberate useless use for educative purposes. :-) I see the accepted answer is precisely my answer without any context or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
for my $key (sort{ my ($x,$y)=@hash_array{$a,$b}; @$y <=> @$x } keys %hash_array) {

    print "key: $key\n";
}
```